# Spark : Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE When Joining 2 Large DFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Folks,

I am running into this issue while I am trying to join 2 large dataframes (100GB + each) in spark on one single key identifier per row.

I am using Spark 1.6 on EMR and here is what I am doing :

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:///df1/")
val df2 = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:///df2/")

// clean up and filter steps later 

df1.registerTempTable("df1")
df2.registerTempTable("df2")

val df3 = sql("select df1.*, df2.col1 from df1 left join df2 on df1.col3 = df2.col4")

df3.write.json("hdfs:///df3/")
```

This is basically the gist of what I am doing, among other clean-up and filter steps in between to join df1 and df2 finally.

Error I am seeing is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:860)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1250)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetLocal(BlockManager.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocal(BlockManager.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:625)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Configuration and References :**
I am using 13 node 60GB each cluster with executors and driver memory set accordingly with overheads. Things I have tried adjusting :

- `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout`
- `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

I have also tried using bigger cluster, but did not help. [This link](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications) says if Shuffle partition size exceeds 2GB, this error is thrown. But I have tried increasing number of partitions to a much high value, still no luck.

I suspect this could be something related to lazy loading. When I do 10 operations on a DF, they are only executed at the last step. I tried adding `.persist()` on various storage levels for DFs, still it doesn't succeed. I have also tried dropping temp tables, emptying all the earlier DFs for clean up.

However the code works if I break it down into 2 parts - writing the final temp data (2 data frames) to the disk, exiting. Restarting to only join the two DFs.

I was earlier getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashOuterJoin.doExecute(BroadcastHashOuterJoin.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.toJSON(DataFrame.scala:1724)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

But  when I adjusted `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout`, I started getting the first error.

Would appreciate any help in this case. I can add more info if needed.

Comment: the property you should try to adjust is `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (note the `s` atfer partition)

Comment: Thats right. Corrected the typo. Thanks

Comment: Could be due to data skew. Try to find out if you have a single join key that is much larger than all the others.

Comment: @LiMuBei Each row is distinct, and has a unique ID in both DFs. Join would result in 1 row output too (1 on 1).

Comment: Hmm... have you tried manually repartitioning the dataframes before the join?

Comment: @LiMuBei yes, various numbers of partitions, also on join key. I also tried caching them. No luck.

Comment: Try repartitioning by the unique id, caching, and then performing a simple action like `count`.  This forces at the outset an equal repartition of the records.  I've used this to avoid having some partitions that are too big.  Also, like Raphael and Sruthi said, tune `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.

Answer (score 6):

In spark u can’t have shuffle block larger than 2GB. This is because, 
Spark stores shuffle blocks as [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Here’s how you allocate it:

`ByteBuffer.allocate(int capacity)`

As, ByteBuffer’s are limited by Integer.MAX_SIZE (2GB), So are shuffle blocks!! Solution is to Increase number of partitions either by using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` in SparkSQL or by `rdd.partition() or rdd.colease()` for rdd's such that each partition size is <= 2GB.

You mentioned that you tried to increase num of partitions and still it failed. Can you check if the partition size was > 2GB. Just make sure that number of partitions specified is sufficient enough to make each block size < 2GB